# Export Excel sheet into Access Table & overwrite (or rename and create new)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been trying to figure out a way to export a sheet from Excel into an Access MDB using VBA (from Excel side). The process is that the user chooses the MDB and actually imports the table FROM Access into Excel. The data then gets chopped/manipulated within Excel. I had no problem with the import as I had done it before however I can't figure out how to export the changed data back into the Access table it came from, overwriting it with the newly changed data.

Basically, lets say the table name is "dt_hsd_texture" and it may have 100K rows in it, it comes into Excel and gets cut down to the requirements it needs to be, and then I want to export the remaining data back into the same table (or rename old table and add new one) which will be less rows (say 10-20K). At the moment my method is just manually copying the data.
I would prefer a rename of the old table to say something like "_ALL" at the end and create a new one. This way I could also duplicate this to do another sheet which is the list of what the data is.

I've searched around but most of what I could find is code for within Access, not Excel. I attempted trying the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` after creating an instance of `Access.Application` but I couldn't get it to work, plus it seemed slow so I'm looking more at an SQL query if that's possible. Something like the `INSERT INTO` type thing if I read that correctly. For when I import the table/database from Access into Excel I use `DAO.Database` and an SQL query to select the table and copy the recordset so if it's able to be done using DAO.Database that would be preferred.

Information such as filename/location will be a variable. Table name will be the sheet name. The first row in the sheet has all the headers.

If someone could help me get past this road block that would be fantastic. I'm not a VBA novice but only with Excel. My expertise for Access is very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have gone for a loop method adding the results. See the code below:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, arr, _
lrow As Long, lcol As Long, TblName As String, Info As Worksheet, StrPath As String, tbldf As DAO.TableDef

Set Info = Sheets("Info")
TblName = Info.Range("R6").Value
StrPath = Info.Range("R7").Value

Set ws = Sheets(TblName)
lrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lcol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(lrow, lcol)).Value
Set db = OpenDatabase(StrPath)

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(TblName)

For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    If rs.Fields(i).Name <> ws.Cells(1, i + 1).Value Then
        MsgBox "There is a mis-match of the headers between the database and Excel sheet. You will need to ensure these are matched up " & _
        "before you continue", vbExclamation, "Mis-matched data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

On Error Resume Next
Set tbldf = db.TableDefs(TblName & "_ALL")
On Error GoTo 0
If tbldf Is Nothing Then
    db.Execute ("SELECT * INTO [" & TblName & "_ALL] FROM " & TblName)
End If

db.Execute "DELETE * FROM " & TblName

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    rs.AddNew
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        rs.Fields(j - 1) = arr(i, j)
    Next j
    rs.Update
Next i

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
```

Testing on a 68 column x 105K row table of data, it ran in just under 30 seconds on my machine which is plenty acceptable for me. This is not the full code I will use but is the code I needed from my question.

I managed this through a lot of help from Chris Maurer's answers/comments as well as searching. Thank you Chris for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this gets way easier if you ODBC-map your Excel table into Access as an Access table.  This will allow you to execute all your data transfers as "Insert Into Select From" SQL statements.

If you have used DAO in the past you already know how to open your Access data base using the OpenDatabase method and you could save that database object in a static (global) VBA variable so the Access db remains open while you do your Excel slicing & dicing.

Let's call that global variable 'db'.  When you are ready to put the Excel data back into Access just call an Excel VBA procedure to `db.Execute("Delete from MyAccessTable")` which cleans out the old data, and then `db.Execute("Insert into MyAccessTable Select * from MyExcelTable")`, assuming your Excel & Access tables are 1:1.  You can tailor your Select if they are not.  You may have to issue a final `db.Execute("Commit")` to get it to stick, I don't know.

Remarks:

1. It is a little-known fact that Access executes Delete queries without Where clauses as a "Truncate Table" style of command, which is considerably faster than cleaning out the table on a record-by-record basis.
2. For extra credit you could try to make a transaction out of the whole thing with BeginTrans and CommitTrans, but you'll need a Workspace object to make that happen, and anyway I'm not sure you can Rollback a Truncate Table command.
3. With this ODBC mapping you can also change how you get this into Excel in the first place by letting Access do the work.  `db.Execute("Insert into MyExcelTable Select * from MyAccessTable")` should efficiently transfer the data in one simple command.
4. After deleting >100k records and re-adding them, the space usage in Access will probably be messed up so you'll want to Compact & Repair Database afterwards.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I tried the delete command in a copy of the mdb and it did clear all data from the table (took a few seconds). However, Is it possible to rename the table instead (adding _ALL to the end of it) and then insert a new table that had the previous name? I would like to be able to keep all the original data as a copy just in case). Also in the `insert` command, what exactly should be put for the `MyExcelTable` bit? As obviously it is only 1 specific sheet.

Comment: I've also never heard of ODBC mapping so have no idea what that entails. I'd rather stick to something I have some sort of knowledge about.

Comment: I just figured out I can rename the table by using `db.TableDefs(TblName).Name = TblName & "_ALL"`. In regards to inserting a new table would it just be your insert line without the `into` ?

Comment: Access has some non-standard SQL called a Make Table query.  So yeah, you can rename your old table, Make a new table with all the right fields, copying all your Excel data in at the same time.  But, that means your DB must temporarily  hold twice the data.  You know Access DBs can only grow to 2 GB before they fail (31 bit internal pointers), if you're not close to that,  fine.  If you're near that, you may want to seek a solution that does require you to keep twice your data

Comment: If you want to db.Execute a Make Table query, check the syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Thanks that did help. I figure I can duplicate the table using `db.Execute("SELECT * INTO [" & TblName & "_ALL] FROM " & TblName)`. That way I don't need to rename it. I can then delete the data in the orig table using your Delete code. However my last query is what do I put as `MyExcelTable` for the insert? If the sheet is named `dt_hsd_texture` and I want all of that sheet to go in (headers are exact same as table as it was imported from there), what do I put?

Comment: Did you map your Excel table into Access using ODBC?  If you do that you can write SQL directly against the data in Excel and insert it into an Access table in a single SQL statement

Comment: In Access, click the External data ribbon, click New Data Source..From File..Excel.  In the dialogue box that comes up Browse to your Excel file, and select the radio button that says "Link to the Data Source by creating a linked table".  That Excel sheet will now appear in your list of Access tables, and you can write SQL against it.

Comment: I'm sorry but doing that defeats the whole purpose of the VBA code. Is there no way to import the sheet through Excel VBA into Access without having to open the mdb? If I have to open the mdb to import it then all I'm doing is pointless.

Comment: I found out where I was going wrong with the transferspeadsheet and it works. Although does seem a bit on the slow side. Still if theres a way to do it through the ADO connection that would be best if you can think of anything.

Comment: You're not getting it.  1. Just link the Excel sheet into Access as MyExcelSheet. This is a one-time action to make the Excel data visible to Access queries.  Once it is linked like that you can close the Access data base and do the rest in Excel.  2. Write the code in **EXCEL** to `db.Execute "Select * Into NewAccessTable From MyExcelSheet".  It's as simple as that.  But you need the MyExcelSheet table object in Access to execute that query.

Comment: I did this myself this afternoon just to verify that it works.

Comment: Then it can't be done. This will be done to multiple different databases which is why I need it to run all in Excel. If I need to open the Access database at all to do anything then the point of the code is useless. I understand I didn't specify that it can be multiple different databases so my apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

So, now I understand that there are many of these Access DBs and one Excel sheet to open all of them, take their data, make changes to the data, and save the resulting changes.  The solution should not include creating permanent objects in the Access DB.

After a bit of playing around I discovered you can execute queries against connection strings without actually linking the tables.

If you have a database object "db" open and pointing to the Access data base, you can do something like this:

```
db.Execute "SELECT * Into MyAccessTable From [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Chris\Temp\TableData.xlsx;].['ofxdownload-1$']"
```

The first part is SQL for a "Make Table" query that will create table MyAccessTable in the Access DB.  It gets a little strange with the data source after From.  This came from a connection string on a linked Excel spreadsheet.  You can see that Connection String in the table properties of the linked Excel table.
[image]

I suggest you do the same because your connection properties may be a bit different than mine depending on what version of Office you are running.

1. Go into one Access data base and link your spreadsheet into Access.  You will only do this once to pick up the correct connection string.
2. Right-click on the newly-linked table and select Design View
3. On the Design Ribbon, click the Property Sheet button
4. In the Property Sheet, Copy the Description to the clipboard
5. Go over to your Excel VBA code and create a db.Execute with SQL that looks like "Select * Into NewTable From []
6. Paste the connection string inside the square brackets.
7. Edit the connection string - Take the TABLE='name' out of the square brackets, and add a dot, another set of square brackets, and the desired sheet name inside in single quotes.  The result should look like [Excel *blah,blah,blah*;DATABASE=*myExcelFileName*;].['*Sheetname*']

I was able to execute that within Excel successfully.

Comment: In order for me to do that I had to re-save the MDB into an ACCDB file type as it wouldn't allow linking as MDB is an older format. This is what I did: `Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\ODC Reseals\2021044 - Copy.accdb")`
Next line: `db.Execute "SELECT * Into dt_hsd_texture From [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\ODC Reseals\dt_hsd_texture_ODC.xlsm;].['dt_hsd_texture']"`

Comment: Unfortunately I receive `Runtime error 3011  Application-defined or object-defined error` . NB: I tried with the table already in database and after deleting

Comment: I appreciate the help you have given me. I've figured to do a loop through columns/rows adding them 1 by 1. I thought this method would be a lot slower, but putting the range into an array I successfully transferred 68 columns x 105K rows in 22 seconds for the entire sub (including deleting previous data in table) which I am more than happy with. Considering I'm also doing this on my home computer and the work computers are faster it will be even better. I've upvoted your answers but I can't really accept either as the complete solution.